# Angular JS 1.6 ngRoute ERROR

Tags: angularjs

I install angularjs with yoeman.
but ngRoute is not working.

I using angular, angular-route 1.6.6
link have '!#'

when I write angular.module ...  in index.html
route is working.

How does app.js work?

my code

scripts/app.js

```
angular.module('myPageApp', ['ngRoute'])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'main'
    })
    .when('/about', {
      templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
      controller: 'AboutCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'about'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });
});
```

index.html

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="#!/">Home</a></li>
  <li><a ng-href="#!/about">About</a></li>
  <li><a ng-href="#/">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="container">
  <ng-view></ng-view>
  <div ng-view></div>
</div>

<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular-route.js"></script>

<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/about.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Comment: What is working? and  what is not working?

Comment: ng-view is not working.
When I click the a tag(ng-href="#!/"), Do not load view(main.html)

Comment: Check the console for error in developer tool

Comment: Vs code console and Chrome console is not have error

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/ZsJsaIzmbUxE50M3GpBS?p=preview try this

Comment: @PunithJain Wowwww Thanks lol :) :) :)
Works Thank you!
I try this, and modify template : <p>~</p> -> tmplateUrl: 'views~'.
that is too Success.
Thank you goooood

Answer (score 0):

Try this scripts/app.js:

```
angular.module('myPageApp', ['ngRoute'])
  .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'main'
    })
    .when('/about', {
      templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
      controller: 'AboutCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'about'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
});
```

index.html

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
  <li><a ng-href="#/about">About</a></li>
  <li><a ng-href="#/">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Hope it helps..